# ccfollow actions in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, tap

ccfollow actions  is following my projectile  correctly. when, double tap recognised.

see the below code. were am mistaken.

here is my code:-

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {
    if (numTaps==1 ) {
[self runAction:[CCFollow actionWithTarget:nextProjectile worldBoundary:CGRectMake(0,0,1050,350)]];
            }
}

- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    numTaps = [[touches anyObject] tapCount];
 printf("Tapcount : %d",numTaps);
    if (numTaps ==1) {

    nextProjectile = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Weapon.png"] retain];
    nextProjectile.position =  ccp(nextprojectile .contentSize.width/2+65, nextprojectile.contentSize.height/2+70);
[nextProjectile runAction:[CCSequence actions: [here's my nextprojectile actions],nil]];
}
}
```

after seen the above code. a question raised by you.
why am mentioning the ccfollow action in if condition.

answer is here,
ordinarily, am mention in update function it will not works, when i set this if condition it works after double tap recognised.

how to rectify this issue?

any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

not in update, try this coding in

```
[self runAction:[CCFollow actionWithTarget:nextProjectile worldBoundary:CGRectMake(0,0,1050,350)]];
            }
```

when adding your projectile. some thing like in your code `[self addchild: nextprojectile];`

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem/issue - you mention double taps, but then code is "numTaps == 1".

Are you saying it only works for double taps, but you want it to work for single taps?

What is working? What is not working?

Have you tried the [cocos2d forums](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/)?

Comment: i want automatically follows the projectile. ok